# Binary Search Tree insertion using C++ Class Segmentation fault

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to implement insertion for a Binary Search Tree class in C++ yet I keep getting segmentation fault. I'm trying to do it with only one class:

Here's my code:

```
class BinarySearchTree{
public:
BinarySearchTree(int n);
BinarySearchTree* tree;
BinarySearchTree* right;
BinarySearchTree* left;
int treekey;
BinarySearchTree* insert(int n, BinarySearchTree*& thetree);
}

BinarySearchTree::BinarySearchTree(int n){
tree = new BinarySearchTree();
tree->left = NULL;
tree->right = NULL;
tree->treekey = n;
cout<<"Treekey is "<<tree->treekey<<endl;
}

BinarySearchTree* BinarySearchTree::insert(int n, BinarySearchTree*& thetree){
cout<<"the tree tree key now is "<<thetree->treekey<<endl;
if(thetree == NULL){
    cout<<"is empty"<<endl;
    tree = new BinarySearchTree(n);
    return tree;
}
cout<<"not empty"<<endl;
cout<<"Treekey here is "<<thetree->treekey<<endl;
if(n<thetree->treekey){
    thetree->left = insert(n, thetree->left);
}else{
    thetree->right = insert(n, thetree->right);
}
return thetree;
}



int main(){
BinarySearchTree* newtree= new BinarySearchTree(16);
newtree -> insert(13, newtree);
return 0;
}
```

My current code outputs:

```
Treekey is 16
the tree tree key now is -1550649400 
not empty
Treekey here is -1550649400
Segmentation fault: 11
```

Sorry that I'm really new to this. Please help me with this, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is basically fine, except that you are invoking undefined behavior when you access a member of `theTree` unconditionally. Just move that line after the check:

```
BinarySearchTree* BinarySearchTree::insert(int n, BinarySearchTree*& thetree){
  if(thetree == NULL){
     // ... 
  }
  cout<<"the tree tree key now is "<<thetree->treekey<<endl;
  // ^^^^ moved this line to after the if
```

Also, you are missing the default constructor for your class. You can reinstate it with:

```
BinarySearchTree() = default;
```

Also, you should use give defaults to all your members:

```
BinarySearchTree* tree = nullptr;
BinarySearchTree* right = nullptr;
BinarySearchTree* left = nullptr;
int treekey{};
```

Note that `nullptr` is what you should be using instead of `NULL` in your code.